# Импорт модуля из самого модуля в Python

Tags: python

```
#файл cf.py
a=1    
b=2
c=3
import cf
print(cf.a, cf.b, cf.c)
```

Модуль импортирует себя для доступа к переменным через его атрибуты.
Во-первых, почему операция импортирования в этом модули не зацикливается(модуль импортирует сам себя) по сути интерпретатор не должен дойти до инструкции print

Во-вторых, почему при импортировании модуля из самого модуля, в IDLE инструкция print срабатывает 2 раза(т.е ответ - 123 123), а при запуске в консоли 1 раз.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Дело в том, что в питоне есть такая штука - `sys.modules`. Когда ты вызываешь `import` (по сути это обращение к функции `__import__()`), модуль, который ты импортируешь (или из которого импортируешь) исполняется через `exec` в отдельном неймспейсе и добавляется в словарь `sys.modules`. НО! Так происходит только и только в том случае, если имя модуля ещё отсутствует в данном словаре. А теперь проведём небольшой эксперимент. Есть такая системная переменная в питоне - `__name__`. Давайте выведем её сразу после строки с цифрами:

```
print(cf.a, cf.b, cf.c)
print(__name__)
```

И вот что мы получим:

```
>>> 
1 2 3
cf
1 2 3
__main__
```

Это не удивительно. Потому что любой вызываемый модуль по умолчанию называется не именем файла или пакета, а именно `__main__`. Соответственно, когда программа натыкается на импорт данного модуля, в словаре `sys.modules` пока ещё нет модуля под названием `cf` (зато есть модуль под названием `__main__`, но это не так важно). Но вот когда программа натыкается на импорт во второй раз, ей уже нет нужды прогонять файл `cf.py` через `exec`, потому что в словаре `sys.modules` уже есть ключ с названием `cf`, значением которого является, собственно, объект модуля.

А вот как это у тебя получилось, что в консоли он выводит цифры только один раз, я не знаю. Покажи как исполняешь, что ли.

Comment: 1.То есть я правильно понял: когда поток выполения доходит до инструкции import в главном модуле(__main__), сразу же после выполнения import cf, имя cf добавляется в sys.modules(не дожидаясь конца инчтпукция в файле). А когда доходит до инструкции import cf, просто ее пропускает и выполняет инструкцию print. Затем поток возвращается в модуль __main__ и довершает инструкции, в __main__ выполнением ф-и print? если так то понятно почему не возникает зацикливание и инструкция print вып-ся 2 раза?
2. НО все равно в консоли вывод 1 раз. А у вас в консоли 2 раза вывод?

Comment: Я извиняюсь второй вопрос снят. дело в том что в консоле я запускал модуль cf.py инструкцией import,(а не указанием имени файла). поэтому он и не грузился повторно.

Comment: Да, всё верно. Именно по этой причине рекомендуют избегать цикличного импорта, потому что при неаккуратном использовании интерпретатор просто натолкнётся на неполный модуль в sys.modules